# Reading training data from text file

Tags: python

I have some training data that when I assign it to a variable in a jupyter notebook it seems to automatically convert to an object,

for example

```
train_data = [("Uber blew through $1 million a week", [(0, 4, 'ORG')]),("Android Pay expands to Canada", [(0, 11, 'PRODUCT'), (23, 30, 'GPE')])]
```

but when I read the same data from text file using

```
with open(path, 'r') as myfile:
  data = myfile.read()
```

and assign it to the train_data variable  I'm no longer to iterate over the objects in the training script

```
for _, annotations in train_data:
    for ent in annotations.get('entities'):
        ner.add_label(ent[2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

erotavlas. File.read() returns a string, which isn't the type of object you're treating it as. You could evaluate the string when you read it like `data = eval(myfile.read())`, but that might be a security risk depending on where you're using this. Another solution would be to use the json library documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). Hope this is useful to you!

Answer (score 1):

You're likely confusing variables and strings. The first example is a variable of type list, the contents of a file are returned as a string. You have to parse it into an appropriate format first.